# Multiple correlation

Tags: statistics, correlation

My question is very elementary. I need to implement a software that computes the multiple correlation of a set of datas that I have. In order to do that, I need would like to find the generic formula of the multiple correlation. Can anyone give it to me?

Please excuse me for asking such a question, but I never studied statistics, and at my working place I don´t have easy access to scientific books. I tried to google it, but I could not find a well-defined formula.

Comment: There already does exist tons of software (comercial as well as free software) which does this for you. Why cannot you use any of them? Besides, programming this is not really elementary, doing it without knowing the relevant theory+numerical linear algebra is ill-adwised!

Comment: I have to use fortran, it´s not my choice. I am a mathematician, and I know quite well programming, linear algebra, number theory and numerical analysis. I just don´t remember the formula of the multiple correlation.

Comment: For formulas, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_correlation     the way to compute is it first compute the multiple regression model $Y=X \beta + \epsilon$, then you go from there.

Comment: I am a Fortran developer. You will find many free Fortran libraries which will be very easy to implement for that.

Comment: Can you give me a link? Thank you